# Problema con posicionamiento usando Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

No puedo hacer que la img me quede al lado del contenido principal con Bootstrap.

Estoy aprendiendo a usar bootstrap e intentando hacer una pagina donde tenga el contenido principal y al lado un aside con una imagen. El problema es que cuando los pongo la imagen se me posiciona debajo del contenido principal.

No sé cual es el problema, intente solucionarlo con CSS dándole un float pero tampoco funciono.

No entiendo si el problema es porque estoy usando mal el bootstrap o si tengo que agregarle algo más.

Este es mi código:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ARCADIA</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos/estilos.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Tiro+Devanagari+Marathi:ital@1&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="menu">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    
                    <ul>
                        <li class="col-md-3">
                            <a href="index.html"><img class="logo" src="imagenes/logo.png"></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="col-md-2">
                            <a href="index.html">Inicio</a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="col-md-2">
                            <a href="index.html">Nosotros</a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="col-md-2">
                            <a href="index.html">Productos</a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="col-md-2">
                            <a href="index.html">Contacto</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <section class="section1">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="articleprincipal ">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <h1>ARCADIA<br><span>TU TIENDA</span></h1>
                            <p>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam at malesuada ante. Donec eu velit id tortor convallis elementum. Curabitur tincidunt eleifend ultricies. In rutrum sapien a venenatis imperdiet. Sed vel eros eu erat ornare sollicitudin vel sit amet eros. Curabitur vel porttitor nibh. Nam aliquet diam lobortis enim volutpat, eget cursus nisi porta. Duis consectetur erat nec nulla congue tristique. Quisque vulputate, eros ut dictum ullamcorper, lectus mi commodo metus, ac hendrerit ex mauris vitae quam. Aliquam semper consequat tortor, vel commodo dui semper ut. Cras vitae magna placerat metus egestas finibus in eget massa. Ut lobortis mi metus, sed gravida ligula mollis at. Donec varius, massa eget ullamcorper pulvinar, ex purus ornare lectus, mattis tristique elit mi in elit. Duis tristique, mi eget cursus convallis, purus augue porta risus, sed faucibus augue mauris ut lacus.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="asideimg col-md-6">
                        <img src="imagenes/productos.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <br>
        <br>
        <hr>
    
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Y este es el código del css en donde intente arreglarlo con un float right en el aside de la img.

```
/**CAMBIOS NAV**/
.logo{
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
}
.menu{
    background: white;
}

.menu ul li{
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.menu ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.menu ul li a:hover{
    background: #FAEAC9;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 var(--link-1);
    transition: color 0.3s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.3s ease-in-out;
    color: var(--link-1);
    color: white;
    box-shadow: inset 100px 0 0 0 var(--link-1);

}

/** CAMBIOS CONTENIDO PRINCIPAL**/


.articleprincipal h1{
    color: black;
    font-size: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Tiro Devanagari Marathi', serif;
}

.articleprincipal p{
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Tiro Devanagari Marathi', serif;
}

.asideimg{
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Si usas bootstrap intenta usar el mínimo de CSS personalizado posible, sobretodo si es relativo a posicionamiento pues bootstrap ya tiene clases para todo eso y al mezclarlo con CSS personalizado los resultados son totalmente imprevisibles.  En cuanto a tu problema, no se el tamaño de la imagen, pero fíjate que le quieres dar 6 columnas, lo cual parece exagerado si se viera bien. En cuanto al posicionamiento, estas anidando columnas sin agregar filas... es decir, esto nunca esta bien: `<div class="col-12"><div class="col-6>`. Debe ser `<div class="col-12"><div class="row"><div class="col-6">`

Comment: Intenta ir arreglando eso y edita tu pregunta con el nuevo código si aún tienes problemas (que los tendras, pues tienes algunos fallos más)

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.